# Using material ui createStyles

Tags: reactjs, typescript, less, material-ui, jss

I'm trying to transform my css from a less file to material createStyles and i can't get my head around how it works.

I understand the basics of the createstyles but i can't my child selector working

All i want is to be able to access the css class missionStatusLibelle

```
.missionStatus {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 34px;
  width: 100%;

  .missionStatusLibelle {
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 20px;
  }

}
```

like

```html
<div className={styles.missionStatusLibelle}>
```

And transform it into something like this

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    missionStatus: {
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      height: "34px",
      width: "100%",

      missionStatusLibelle: {
        alignItems: "flex-start",
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
        marginLeft: "10px",
        fontSize: "14px",
        fontWeight: 500,
        lineHeight: "20px"
      }
    }
}));
```

But i can't get to missionStatusLibelle apart from using pseudo-selectors.

```
const styles = useStyles();
<div className={styles.missionStatusLibelle}>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like the following:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    missionStatus: {
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      height: "34px",
      width: "100%",

      "& $missionStatusLibelle": {
        alignItems: "flex-start",
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
        marginLeft: "10px",
        fontSize: "14px",
        fontWeight: 500,
        lineHeight: "20px"
      }
    },
    missionStatusLibelle: {}
  }
));
```

Here's the relevant documentation: https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.24#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet