# Material UI: affect children based on class

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

#### What I am trying to achieve

I have two classes - `root` and `button` - I want to affect `button` class on `root` state (for example `:hover`).

---

#### My attempt

I'm trying to display `button` on `root:hover`.

```js
const styles = {
   root: {
      '&:hover' {
         // here I can style `.root:hover`
         button: {
            // and I've tried to affect `.root:hover .button` here
            display: 'block'
         }
      }
   },
   button: {
      display: 'none'
   }
}
```

**Expected ouput**:

```css
.element-root-35 .element-button-36:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

**Current output:**

```css
.element-root-35:hover {
  button: [object Object];
}
```

---

#### Environment

I'm using Material-UI with React.js. In this situation I'm using `withStyles()` export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the correct syntax:

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    "&:hover $button": {
      display: "block"
    }
  },
  button: {
    display: "none"
  }
};
```

[image: Edit Nested selector]

Related answers and documentation:

- [jss-plugin-nested documentation](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.24#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet)
- [Using material ui createStyles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871809/using-material-ui-createstyles/57873871#57873871)
- [Advanced styling in material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019444/advanced-styling-in-material-ui/58019642#58019642)