# How do you change a style of a child when hovering over a parent using Material UI styles?

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, material-ui, jss, onhover

I'm using Material UI in react. Let's say I have this component with these styles:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  outerDiv: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[200],
    padding: theme.spacing(4),
    '&:hover': {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[100]
   }
  },
  addIcon: (props: { dragActive: boolean }) => ({
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    color: theme.palette.grey[400],
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
  })
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item className={classes.outerDiv}>
        <AddIcon className={classes.addIcon} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

I want to change the style of `addIcon` when hovering over `outerDiv` using the styles above.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-mcnulty-b1gcd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)'s my example.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Below is an example of the correct syntax for v4 (`"& $addIcon"` nested within `&:hover`). Further down are some v5 examples.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Grid, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  outerDiv: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[200],
    padding: theme.spacing(4),
    '&:hover': {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[100],
      "& $addIcon": {
        color: "purple"
      }
   }
  },
  addIcon: (props: { dragActive: boolean }) => ({
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    color: theme.palette.grey[400],
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
  })
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item className={classes.outerDiv}>
        <AddIcon className={classes.addIcon} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit eager-tesla-xw2cg]

Related documentation and answers:

- https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.0.0#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet
- [how to use css in JS for nested hover styles, Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716926/how-to-use-css-in-js-for-nested-hover-styles-material-ui/57729101#57729101)
- [Material UI: affect children based on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58626226/material-ui-affect-children-based-on-class/58628737#58628737)
- [Advanced styling in material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019444/advanced-styling-in-material-ui/58019642#58019642)

---

For those who have started using Material-UI v5, the example below implements the same styles but leveraging the new `sx` prop.

```
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";

export default function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid
        item
        sx={{
          p: 4,
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[200],
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[100],
            cursor: "pointer",
            "& .addIcon": {
              color: "purple"
            }
          }
        }}
      >
        <AddIcon
          className="addIcon"
          sx={{
            height: "50px",
            width: "50px",
            color: theme.palette.grey[400],
            mb: 2
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit hover over parent]

---

Here's another v5 example, but using Emotion's `styled` function rather than Material-UI's `sx` prop:

```
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro";

const StyledAddIcon = styled(AddIcon)(({ theme }) => ({
  height: "50px",
  width: "50px",
  color: theme.palette.grey[400],
  marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
}));
const StyledGrid = styled(Grid)(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(4),
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[200],
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[100],
    cursor: "pointer",
    [`${StyledAddIcon}`]: {
      color: "purple"
    }
  }
}));
const theme = createTheme();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Grid container>
        <StyledGrid item>
          <StyledAddIcon />
        </StyledGrid>
      </Grid>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit hover over parent]

---

And one more v5 example using Emotion's css prop:

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";

const theme = createTheme();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid
          item
          css={(theme) => ({
            padding: theme.spacing(4),
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[200],
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[100],
              cursor: "pointer",
              "& .addIcon": {
                color: "purple"
              }
            }
          })}
        >
          <AddIcon
            className="addIcon"
            css={(theme) => ({
              height: "50px",
              width: "50px",
              color: theme.palette.grey[400],
              marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
            })}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit hover over parent]

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link it is helping a lot !

Comment: And it also possible to reference the parent in the child css definition: `'$outerDiv:hover &': { color: 'purple' },`

Comment: perfect! thank you so much!!

Comment: This is a great solution that worked well for me, was useful!

Answer (score 13):

This denotes the current selector which is the parent component:

```
'&': { /* styles */ }
```

This means the parent component in hover state:

```
'&:hover': { /* styles */ }
```

This means the child component inside the parent that is in hover state:

```
'&:hover .child': { /* styles */ }
```

You can also omit the ampersand `&` if you're using a pseudo-class:

```
':hover .child': { /* styles */ }
```

Complete code using `sx` prop (The same style object can also be used in `styled()`):

```
<Box
  sx={{
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    backgroundColor: "darkblue",
    ":hover .child": {
      backgroundColor: "orange"
    }
  }}
>
  <Box className="child" sx={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
</Box>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This is very helpful for material UI v5 with typescript on the SX prop cause it doesn't accept the `&:hover`. but works fine with it and throw a warning. the only way that seemed to work is using `:hover`

Answer (score 2):

Possibly an obvious point, but just to add to the answer above: if you are referencing a separate className, don't forget that you also need to create it in the makeStyles hook or else it won't work. For instance:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  parent: {
    color: "red",
    "&:hover": {
      "& $child": {
        color: "blue" // will only apply if the class below is declared (can be declared empty)
      }
    }
  },
  // child: {} // THIS must be created / uncommented in order for the code above to work; assigning the className to the component alone won't work.
})

const Example = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <Box className={classes.parent}>
      <Box className={classes.child}>
        I am red unless you create the child class in the hook
      </Box>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were using `makeStyles` in MUI v4 and have migrated to MUI v5 then you are likely now importing `makeStyles` from `tss-react`. If that is the case, then you achieve the same by the following:

```
import { makeStyles } from 'tss-react';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme, props, classes) => ({
  outerDiv: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[200],
    padding: theme.spacing(4),
    '&:hover': {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[100],
      [`& .${classes.addIcon}`]: {
        color: "purple"
      }
   }
  },
  addIcon: (props: { dragActive: boolean }) => ({
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    color: theme.palette.grey[400],
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
  })
}));
```

The third argument passed to the `makeStyles` callback is the classes object.

Comment: With Typescript and the latest version of `tss-react`, you have to supply the classes key type, which defaults to `never`: `makeStyles<void, "addIcon">` or `makeStyles<void, string>`.