# Can I make an Icon in a TableRow column change color when hovering anywhere in that row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui 4.9.5.

I've made a cut down example of my problem here. I have a `Table` which I populate with some simple JSON data. Each row data looks like this :

```
{
      icon: {
         {
              iconElement: FolderIcon,
              color: "red",
              hoverColor: "green"
         }
      },
      projectName: "Project1"
}
```

So each row can have it's own icon and its own color and hover color.

[image]

What I am really stuggling with is how to get the hover color for the individual icon to trigger when the user hovers anywhere within that row ?

I have the hover trigger for the row written and trigger a background change on hover. I cannot figure out how to get the icon to change on hover. This is what I have so far :

[image: Edit icon-hover-color-table-row]

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  rowIconStyle: {
    minWidth: 50,
    minHeight: 50
  },
  tableRowStyle: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "darkGrey"
    }
  }
});

export default function MyTableComponent(props) {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const DEFAULT_TABLE_ROW_ICON_COLOR = "grey";
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Icon</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {props.tableRowsData.map(row => {
            const RowIcon =
              row.icon && row.icon.iconElement
                ? row.icon.iconElement
                : () => <div />;
            let iconElement = (
              <RowIcon
                className={styles.rowIconStyle}
                style={{
                  color:
                    row.icon && row.icon.color
                      ? row.icon.color
                      : DEFAULT_TABLE_ROW_ICON_COLOR
                }}
              />
            );
            return (
              <TableRow key={row.name} className={styles.tableRowStyle}>
                <TableCell>{iconElement}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.projectName}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}

MyTableComponent.propTypes = {
  tableRowsData: PropTypes.array
};
```

Any suggestions hugely appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the solution to support IE 11? A particularly clean way of handling this would leverage [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var), but CSS variables aren't supported by IE.

Comment: No I don't. Thankfully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicated that you do not need to support IE, you can leverage [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var). This is particularly helpful since you are managing the hover colors as data and each icon can have a different hover color.

The first step is to provide the two colors you care about for each icon as custom CSS properties (`--icon-color` and `--hover-icon-color` below):

```
            const RowIcon =
              row.icon && row.icon.iconElement
                ? row.icon.iconElement
                : () => <div />;
            const iconColor =
              row.icon && row.icon.color
                ? row.icon.color
                : DEFAULT_TABLE_ROW_ICON_COLOR;
            const iconHoverColor =
              row.icon && row.icon.hoverColor ? row.icon.hoverColor : iconColor;
            let iconElement = (
              <RowIcon
                className={styles.rowIconStyle}
                style={{
                  "--icon-color": iconColor,
                  "--hover-icon-color": iconHoverColor
                }}
              />
```

Then you can leverage these CSS properties in your CSS:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  rowIconStyle: {
    minWidth: 50,
    minHeight: 50,
    color: "var(--icon-color)",
    "$tableRowStyle:hover &": {
      color: "var(--hover-icon-color)"
    }
  },
  tableRowStyle: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "darkGrey"
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit icon-hover-color-table-row]

Related answer: [How do you change a style of a child when hovering over a parent using material-ui jss styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178802/how-do-you-change-a-style-of-a-child-when-hovering-over-a-parent-using-material/59179458#59179458)

Answer (score -2):

Found this not sure it will solve you issue but you can try
for the table

```
<TableBody>
{data.map((row, index) => (
     <TableRow key={index} style={{ padding: '5px 20px', height: 25, ...this.getStripedStyle(index) }}>
           ....Columns
     </TableRow>
))}
</TableBody>
```

Get Striped Style

```
  getStripedStyle(index) {
    return { background: colorArr[index] };
  }
```

Comment: No, that doesn't solve my issue. That's styling the row. It's the icon in a particular TableCell on the row which I was to style on a hover anywhere in the row.