# Target nested material component in JSS style definition

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have this JSX layout currently

```
<div className={classes.bottomArea}>
    <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column">
        <Typography variant="h1" component="span">1982</Typography>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="span">Bed Count</Typography>
    </Box>
</div>
```

And in my styles I'm trying to change the color of the `h5` Typography element

```
bottomArea: {
    $h5: {
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

I think I understand why this isn't working but is there an easy way to target that `h5` variant?

Here is a codesandbox to show

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-wb7ts

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to retain `<span>` as your component, you can target the `h5` variant by targeting the CSS class added by `Typography` which is `MuiTypography-h5`.

In the syntax shown below, the `&` refers to the class generated for `bottomArea` and then the space indicates targeting `.MuiTypography-h5` as a [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator).

```
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  bottomArea: {
    "& .MuiTypography-h5": {
      color: "red"
    }
  }
});

export default function Types() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.bottomArea}>
      <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column">
        <Typography variant="h1" component="span">
          1982
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="span">
          Bed Count
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Target nested typography by variant]

JSS Documentation: https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.3.0#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule

Related answer: [How do you change a style of a child when hovering over a parent using material-ui jss styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178802/how-do-you-change-a-style-of-a-child-when-hovering-over-a-parent-using-material/59179458#59179458)

Comment: will this work in production mode when those classes get converted to the shortened class names? Such as `jss-101` etc.

Comment: @Jordan The Mui classes do not get shortened in production mode in v4 (at least not by default). They did get shortened in v3.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Typography` props the wrong way. The `variant` props only defines the style applied to the component whereas the `component` props defines which tag will be used to render this component.

If you want your `Typography` component to be a `h5`:

```
<Typography variant="h5" component="h5">Bed Count</Typography>
```

And then for the styling:

```
bottomArea: {
    '& h5': {
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

CodeSanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-6i1lq?file=/demo.js

Great day !

Answer (score 0):

you can use `withStyle` to update the specific component classes

check this [Typography API](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/)

```js
const Typography = withStyles(() => ({
  h5: {
    color: "red",
  },
}))(MuiTypography);

export default function Types() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column">
        <Typography variant="h1" component="span">
          1982
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="span">
          Bed Count
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo]